# Django's generic CreateView leading to a 404

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the documentation on Django's [generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) and trying to follow them with a simple example. I have a project `my_project` with an app `my_app` with the following structure:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── forms.py
├── models.py
├── templates
│   └── my_app
│       ├── author_form.html
│       └── contact.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

The `urls.py` is

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ContactView, AuthorCreate

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', AuthorCreate.as_view())
]
```

and the project-level `urls.py` is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_app/', include('my_app.urls'))
]
```

The `views.py` is

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView, CreateView
from my_app.models import Author


class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
```

Note that I have not implemented the `get_absolute_url` method in the example, because it is unclear to me how the `'author-detail'` named URL should be defined.

The problem is, however, that after entering a name and pressing the "Create" button, I get a 404 error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/my_app/create/None
Using the URLconf defined in my_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
my_app/ contact/ [name='contact']
my_app/ create/
The current path, my_app/create/None, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I suspect that the `get_absolute_url` method is somehow critical to the implementation of the `CreateView`, but it's unclear to me from the documentation how to implement the corresponding URL pattern. Should it perhaps be

```
path('create/<int:pk>/', AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author-detail')
```

?

Comment: Looks like you are creating a link to object before it is saved to the database. The PK is `None` then.

Comment: I would suppose that the `CreateView` would create the object though? Perhaps the `author-detail` named URL needs to point to a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) for the `Author` object?

Comment: Or you created the object, but didn't pass its id to the url. Have you used `kwargs={'pk': self.pk}` in the `get_absolute_path`? In fact `get_absolute_url`  
 method from the docs should work with no changes.